# Indexing flat XML files in elasticsearch

Tags: json, xml, mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm working on a specific project where external data provided by external providers is to be indexed on our ElasticSearch Engine.

The data is provided as XML flat files.

The idea here is to script something out that reads each file, parse it and launch as many HTTP POST as needed for each one of them.

Is there a simpler way to do this? something like uploading the XML file that gets indexed automatically without any script?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [logstash with an xml filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/xml) to do this.  Takes a bit of work to get setup the first time, but it's the most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: Weird that ElasticSearch won't support it natively. I saw few plugins, but nothing out of the box that comes with ES.

I do like the idea of using Logstash since it can do the ingest part for you and you can add couple of filters to massage the data a little before you insert it into ES.

Comment: one gripe I have with logstash, if the XML is not flat and you want to flatten the output into ES, be prepared to know/learn some Ruby.